# How to retrieve key value pair from a cfg file

Tags: python, key-value

**I am new to python.**

I have a config file as shown below in the same order. I need to retrieve key, value pairs from config file and will use those values in my script

```
# Name and details 
( 
 { group => 'abc',
   host => 'pqr.com',
   user => 'anonymous',
   src => '/var/tmp',
   dest => '/tmp',
}, 
{ group => 'abc',
  host =>'pqr.com',
  user => 'anonymous',
  src => '/tmp'
  dest => '/var/tmp'
}, 
{ group => 'pqr',
  host =>'abc.com',
  user => 'xyz',
  src => '/home/pp',
  dest => '/var/tmp',
}, 
{ group => 'xyz',
  host =>'p.com',
  user => 'x',
  src => '/home/',
  dest => '/tmp',
}
```

)

Each

```
{

}
```

is considerd as one block..`Group`,`user`,`host` are unique as well as repeated.
I have to read and parse the config file and display key and value pair.Pls help.

```
Key : group,Value : 'abc'(say)
key : host ,Value :'pqr.com'
Key : user, Value :'anonymous'
Key : src,Value :'/var/tmp',
key : dest,Value : '/tmp'
```

Thank you,

---

I have written the code which displays keys and values taking cfg file(shown above) as an input.

```
idx = 0
dictList = []
while True:
try:
start = config.index("{", idx)
end = config.index("}", start+1)
slice = config[start+1:end-1]
sliceList = [s.strip() for s in slice.split(",") if s.strip()]
dd = {}
for item in sliceList:
key, value = [s.strip() for s in item.split("=>")]
print key, value
```

Output while displaying keys,values

```
key 'value'
group 'abc'
host 'pqr.com'
user 'ananymous'
src '/use/tmp
```

Now the problem is ,how to display the value corresponding to a key.
Eg : print group- should display abc
print host should display pqr.com, and so on.

Comment: Is that the way group `abc` is in the config file or is it partially duplicated here?

Comment: Hi,It is in the config file...

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to parse it, here's a small example on how to do this.

```
import re
def parse(data):
    '''Parse data block, return itertator on objects inside'''
    for block in re.finditer('{[^}]*}', data, re.M):  # Split to objects
        obj = {}
        for match in re.finditer("([a-z]+) => '([^']*)'", block.group()):
            obj[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
        yield obj
```

Now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Your data is bit malformed to be directly interpreted by Python. So you would have to per-process the data before interpreting it

1. Change all Occurrence of `=>` to `:` : `data.replace("=>",":")`
2. Quote all the Keys : `re.sub(" (\w+) ",r"'\1'",data.replace("=>",":"))`

You can then feed it to `ast.literal_eval`

```
import re,ast
ast.literal_eval(re.sub(" (\w+) ",r"'\1'",data.replace("=>",":")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Can you please explain in brief as how to use ast.literal_eval function for parsing the file.I did it in perl like "eval \@tmp" = @config (where config had contents of config file)..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

You want to try that out for this.

But your config file format will want to change to a more ini format

```
[section]
key = value
```

http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/

demjson also is nice for python objects -> strings and back.

I tend to use these in this situation.